# Select KeyValuePair in a ComboBox with Key

Tags: c#, combobox, keyvaluepair

I have several KeyValuePair in a combobx.

```
this.cbEndQtr.Items.Clear();
this.cbEndQtr.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "Test1"));
this.cbEndQtr.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "Test2"));
```

What's the simplest way to select the by passing in the key. For example something like this:

```
this.cbEndQtr.SelectedItem = 2;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a brute force approach:

```
void selectByKey(int key)
{
    foreach (var item in cbEndQtr.Items)
        if (((KeyValuePair<int, string>)item).Key == key) 
        {
            cbEndQtr.SelectedItem = item;
            break;
        }
}
```

And I just found this one line approach:

```
cbEndQtr.SelectedItem = cbEndQtr.Items.OfType<KeyValuePair<int, string>>().ToList().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Key == key);
```

Although if it doesn't find a match nothing will change.

Comment: Nothing will change in your `for` loop, but your 'one line' approach sets the selected item to `null` if none is found.

Comment: @Silvermind `KeyValuePair` isn't nullable so you end up trying to set `SelectedItem` to a new instance of `KeyValuePair` (the default value).  In my quick test if something was already selected it stayed selected.

Comment: My bad, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `LINQ` like this:

```
var key = 2; // get key from somewhere

var items = this.cbEndQtr.Items.OfType<KeyValuePair<int, string>>()
             .Select((item,index) => new { item, index);

var index = items.Where(x => x.item.Key == key).Select(x => x.index).First();        

this.cbEndQtr.SelectedIndex = index;
```